# checkbox weird behaviour on SG3

Tags: android, checkbox, samsung-mobile

Right, i am playing around with CheckBox on Android. I applied background colour for it which works fine on all devices apart from Galaxy S3. It simply disappears from the screen when i add background colour.

```
                    <CheckBox
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"/>
```

Thats all i have, but its hiding it on S3. Any idea why?

It seems to be happening between API11 and API16. Anything below or above is fine

Comment: I've had a similar problem when using a custom selector on the checkboxes on certain galaxy s3 models. I ended up giving the checkboxes a fixed height and width and it sorted out the issue.

Comment: @WillieNel It was my bad, i should have used android:button to style my button instead of android:background! Duuh!

Comment: Cool, glad you sorted it out. Happy coding! :)